# If $ A$ is diagonalizable by similarity then there is a positive definite Hermitian matrix $ P$ such that $P^{−1}AP$ is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in{M_n}$ and  $ A$ is diagonalizable by similarity.

Why does there is a
positive definite Hermitian matrix $ P$ such that $P^{−1}AP$ is normal?

Answer (score 2):

By assumption, there is some $V$ such that $V^{-1} A V = \Sigma$, where
$\Sigma$ is diagonal.

Let $V^{-1}=UR$ be the polar decomposition of $V^{-1}$, that is $U$ is unitary and $R$ is
positive definite Hermitian. Let $P=R^{-1}$, $P$ is also positive definite Hermitian.

Then $P^{-1}AP = U^* V^{-1} A V U = U^* \Sigma U$, and we can check that $U^* \Sigma U$
is normal.